# Java: How would I write a try-catch-repeat block?

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

I am aware of a counter approach to do this. I was wondering if there is a nice and compact way to do this.

Comment: Please post your own attempts.

Comment: Is there a way to express this as a stream?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Legend - your answer could be improved upon; because if you fail `numTries` times, you swallow the exception. Much better:

```
while (true) {
  try {
    //
    break;
  } catch (Exception e ) {
    if (--numTries == 0) throw e;
  }
}
```

Comment: hm if (--numTries == 0) is really dangerous. What if it is on start 0 or lower ? I would prefer < 1

Answer (score 6):

I have seen a few approaches but I use the following:

```
int numtries = 3;
while(numtries-- != 0)
   try {
        ...
        break;
   } catch(Exception e) {
        continue;
   }
}
```

This might not be the best approach though. If you have any other suggestions, please put them here.

**EDIT: A better approach was suggested by oxbow_lakes. Please take a look at that...**

Comment: This was meant to be one of those answer your own question :) with the hope that it will help others...

Comment: @Legend - I think if you look at my answer, you will see that your approach is flawed

Answer (score 2):

if you are using Spring already, you might want to create an aspect for this behavior as it is a cross-cutting concern and all you need to create is a pointcut that matches all your methods that need the functionality. see http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/aop.html#aop-ataspectj-example

Answer (score 1):

Try aspect oriented programming and [`@RetryOnFailure`](http://www.jcabi.com/jcabi-aspects/annotation-retryonfailure.html) annotation from [jcabi-aspects](http://www.jcabi.com/jcabi-aspects/index.html):

```
@RetryOnFailure(attempts = 2, delay = 10, verbose = false)
public String load(URL url) {
  return url.openConnection().getContent();
}
```